# Pass value from view, ---> Jquery --->another view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

The first view, containing the value i want to pass along looks like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.BlogPosts)
    {
      @item.Id <---This is the id i want to pass along
      <div id="allphotos"><p>Från bildbank</p></div>
    }
```

This is the Jquery triggered by the #allphotos. I need to have the @item.Id with me in here if possible.

```
$("#allphotos").click(function () {

    $("<div></div>")
        .addClass("dialog")
        .appendTo("body")
        .dialog({
        close: function () {
            $(this).remove();
        },
        modal: true,
        height: 600,
        width: 700
    })
        .load("/Home/AllPhotos");
});
```

The Jquery opens up a dialog and in this dialog i need to be able to acess the @item.Id somehow.

Here is the "final"-view where i need to acess the Id:

```
@model aPhoto_web.Models.AdminPages.AdminViewModel

/* Somewhere here i need to be able to read the @itemId in order to be able to pass it in the actionlink below. */

@foreach (var item in Model.Photographys)
{
    <img id="imga" style="max-width: 100px;" src="@item.ImgUrl" />
    <p>@item.ImgUrl</p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New Part", "SetBlogImg", "Home", new {contId = @item.Id, imgurl = @item.ImgUrl}, null)
 }
```

Is it possible to achieve this somehow?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the `ID` as below.

```
<div data-photoid="@(item.Id)" id="allphotos"><p>Från bildbank</p></div>

.load("/Home/AllPhotos?itemid=" + $(this).data("photoid"));
```

In your `controller` change the `AllPhotos` method as below to get the ID.

```
public ActionResult AllPhotos(int itemid)
```

Then when you set the `AdminViewModel` you can use that value.

Comment: This seems like the way to go, Thanks again! It seems that you and Exception are saving the day. Thanks!

Comment: @Exception: It seems both of us are checking MVC related questions.

Answer (score 1):

Give `<div id="allphotos">` a attribute as :

```
<div id="allphotos" data-id="@item.Id">

$("#allphotos").click(function () {
      var id=$(this).attr("data-id");   <-----retrieve data-id here as shown

            $("<div></div>")
                .addClass("dialog")
                .appendTo("body")
                .dialog({
                    close: function() { $(this).remove(); },
                    modal: true,
                    height: 600,
                    width: 700
                })
                .load("/Home/AllPhotos?itemid=" + id);

        });
```

Your Action will look like this :

```
public ActionResult AllPhotos(int itemid){....}
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try this now. But i cant see that the value is getting passed to the new view?

Comment: @user2915962...i think my answer deserve's a upvote atleast not downvote...haha...

Comment: Im sure it does, however, i decided to go with Saranga this time. It seems that the controller gets to do some more work that way. But thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Send the Value to a controller method, then with your 'new' view set @Value== Html.Action(callMethodHere)

There is plenty of documentation about using MVC in its correct way (as view should only be there to VIEW the project, the Controller is there to handle the data!)

Comment: This sound very interesting, I would reallt appreciate if you could provide an example of how to send this value(a string) to a controller that hold that value and let me retrieve it later.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/639709/Getting-Data-From-View-to-Controller-in-MVC <--- This is a great article on it. Pay close attention to the 'return Content(sbInterest.ToString());'